# Can't find pipeline editor anymore

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I have the Blue ocean beta plugin installed and cannot find the pipeline editor. Where should it be? I have the latest version of the plugin installed, I'm sure it used to be an obvious button you could click on when going to the blue ocean view, but it's not there for me anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I encountered the same problem and posted a question in the Cloudbees Community.  One of the Cloudbees engineers responded with this:

"At the moment you can only edit Pipelines that have been created through the "New Pipeline" flow.

However, we are going to restore a general link to access the editor as part of our "Pipeline Playgrounds" work. You can follow progress by logging in to Jenkins JIRA and watching JENKINS-43118."

In the JENKINS-43118 JIRA ticket, there is a comment that says

"We want to restore the link to the "Pipeline Playground" mode of the editor in a less obtrusive place.

This was lost as the editor and creation was merged together"

So, essentially I think this was a regression.

Another comment in the ticket mentions that the editor can still be invoked with a URL like "http://localhost:8080/jenkins/blue/organizations/jenkins/pipeline-editor/". ( I think you would insert the project name for the second "jenkins").  And then, supposedly, you can use keyboard shortcuts like Ctrl/Cmd-S to do the Save since the button isn't there anymore.  I tried this, but things still appear to be broken, so I think we're out of luck until this JIRA issue is resolved. Too bad.

Comment: Ah that's a shame, I wanted to check the syntax of some new blocks I have added to my pipeline. Never mind! Thanks for the info, hopefully they will fix in the next release, can't believe they didn't spot this before pushing the most recent one out!