# Pipeline editor not available

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins `2.121.2` with Blue Ocean `1.7.1` and, while I can access the pipeline editor via the pencil icon for a pipeline created via the Blue Ocean interface, it seems I'm unable to do the same if the pipeline has been created via the classic UI.

Both pipelines are hosted on a git server (not Github) and the same credentials have been used, one has been created as a multibranch pipeline (from Blue Ocean UI) while the other is a plain pipeline (classic UI).

Trying to access the pipeline editor via the direct URL, as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055864/cant-find-pipeline-editor-anymore) doesn't work:

- editor opens, but no content is displayed if I use the URL like [http://](http://_)**host**/blue/organizations/jenkins/pipeline-editor/***project***/
- editor opens, but on an empty pipeline (which should be not) if I use the URL like [http://](http://_)**host**/blue/organizations/jenkins/pipeline-editor/***project***/master

Any solution to this? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Since Blue Ocean is still under development, it is one of the limitation it has.

You can check this thread on how to do it right now 
[Cant open Blue Ocean visual pipeline editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45594701/cant-open-blue-ocean-visual-pipeline-editor)

Basically, you need to click Ctrl+S when you entered the direct link and then copy paste the whole Jenkinsfile code.

Comment: Tried your suggestion, but that doesn't allow me to save the changes: I get a `fetch failed: 404 for http://my-server/blue/rest/organizations/jenkins/pipelines/my-project/scm/content/`

Comment: At first you copy the code from the file to Ctrl+S window and click update. After you are done editing it, you click Ctrl+S again and copy-paste it into the original file. This is a work-around since it doesn't work at the moment, but it's the best way to have a nice editor for pipelines.

Comment: That practically means the editor doesn't integrate with Git :-(

Comment: Yeah, I tried creating a dummy project and it didn't work as well. So I guess only the workaround is working at the moment, however, Blue Ocean is open source so we can always try and implement it the right way. I'll take a look at it later unless someone comes up with something else meanwhile.